# How do i print the return value for a conditional statement

Tags: python

How do I return the Boolean  value of `if not 2 >= 3:` in the following code?

How do I get the value of the result from the if statement before? I know its "True", but how do i refer to it?

```
def using_control_once():
    if not 2 >= 3:
        return "Success"


print using_control_again()

def using_control_once():
    if not 2 >= 3:
        return "Controlled"


print using_control_once()
```

I would like to print the value of the if statement after evaluating `not 2 >= 3` rather than the assigned value to the return function

Comment: You mean `print(not 2 >= 3)` ?

Comment: just `return not 2 >= 3`

Comment: You mean you wanna print "Succes" or "Controlled" ?

Answer (score 1):

In the below code I haven't assigned any new value to the condition variable.
We are just returning the value from condition itself here.

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
def using_control_once():
    condition = not 2 >= 3
    if condition:
        return condition

print(using_control_once())
```

Answer (score 0):

in python, in a conditional statement like:

```
if <condition>:
    <statement>
```

`<condition>` gets [evaluated in a boolean context](https://realpython.com/python-operators-expressions/#logical-operators), but it not saved in a variable. You have two alternatives here:

1) If you only need to print the Truth value of the condition:

```
print(<condition>)
```

as suggested by Devesh Kumar Singh, or, to be on the safe side:

```
print(str(<condition>))
```

2) if you need the if statement:

```
if <condition>:
    print("True")
    <other statement>
else:
    print("False")
    <other statement>
```

I hope that helps. I would also recommend reading this article on [Conditional Statements in Python](https://realpython.com/python-conditional-statements/)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to keep track of when and how conditions are evaluated, you can do something like this:

```py
from inspect import getouterframes, currentframe, getsourcelines
import re

def test(exp):
    frame_info = getouterframes(currentframe(), 2)[1]
    result = re.search(f'{test.__name__}[ ]*\(([^\)]+)\)', frame_info.code_context[1], re.DOTALL)
    condition = '{} is {}'.format(result.group(1), bool(exp))
    print(condition)

    return bool(exp)


def using_control_once(x):
    if test(x < 10):
        return "Success #1"

    if test(x < 20):
        return "Success #2"

    if test(x < 30):
        return "Success #3"


print("x=3")
result = using_control_once(3)
print(f"result is: {result}")

print("\nx=13")
result = using_control_once(13)
print(f"result is: {result}")

print("\nx=23")
result = using_control_once(23)
print(f"result is: {result}")
```

The output will be:

```sh
x=3
x < 10 is True
result is: Success #1

x=13
x < 10 is False
x < 20 is True
result is: Success #2

x=23
x < 10 is False
x < 20 is False
x < 30 is True
result is: Success #3
```

Answer (score -1):

Much thanks guys, am grateful for the diligence Victor,  I am still new to python and programming in general. This will take sometime to understand but am glad its doable.

```
def test(exp):
    frame_info = getouterframes(currentframe(), 2)[1]
    result = re.search(f'{test.__name__}[ ]*\(([^\)]+)\)', 
    frame_info.code_context[1], re.DOTALL)
    condition = '{} is {}'.format(result.group(1), bool(exp))
    print(condition)

    return bool(exp)
```